# Creating Multiple Fields at Once

Tags: apex, community

I have been tasked with creating ~150 new fields on a new object because we want to start getting historical snap shots of data.

Creating 150 new fields is cumbersome - What options do I have for expediting the process? I have looked online and found some posts that dive into XML. Not really sure what the actual template for that should look like or how to even import that into my org. I was thinking workbench? Overall, would love some help on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Templating field metadata in XML is not especially difficult. While the [Metadata API reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm) for the `CustomObject` entity is the exhaustive guide, I found it easiest when I did a lot of this some years ago to just pull down an example custom object's metadata from a developer org.

That effort led to [this](https://gist.github.com/davidmreed/a7218caf92ab9cf363d4ada9063bab59) (obsolete and rather ugly) Python script, the relevant bits being, e.g.

```
templates["Checkbox"] = """
    <fields>
        <fullName>%(fullName)s__c</fullName>
        <defaultValue>false</defaultValue>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>%(label)s</label>
        <type>Checkbox</type>
    </fields>
"""
templates["Date"] = """
    <fields>
        <fullName>%(fullName)s__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>%(label)s</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Date</type>
    </fields>
"""
```

(and so on).

Following, a loop over some data structure containing the desired schema information can easily template out the metadata so that you can paste it into a `CustomObject` XML metadata file and deploy it to Salesforce:

```
for entry in some_list_of_schema:
    print(templates[entry["type"]].format(entry))
```

It's a quick-and-dirty method that omits, e.g., Profile and Page Layout management, but if what you need is simply to generate a very large volume of Salesforce field definitions quickly, a script along those lines will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have a paid tool to do this, the salesforce toolkit on heroku (https://fieldcreator.herokuapp.com/) can give you an easier way of making a bunch of fields at once.

If this is to retrieve information I would consider adding an external source to pull this historic data, but if it is for storing then I personally would use this tool or pull the object xml.  Not the best answer but better than clicking new 150 times.  I am sure someone will post a better method using the metadata api but I am not sure how.